# android - overridden volume button has affected back button?

Tags: android, overriding, volume, back, android-audiomanager

Using the code below I have stopped the use of the volume buttons unless I am streaming audio (otherwise it annoyingly changes the ringer volume), but the 'Back' button isn't working.

Pressing 'back' should got to my phones desktop (or exit my app, like you would expect), but it isn't doing anything. If I open the menu, 'Back' will close the menu as it should, but I can't leave the app.

I have copied the code onto other activities within my app, if I open another activity within my app, because the 'Back' button isn't working, I can't go back to the main screen :)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Suppress the use of the volume keys unless we are currently listening to the stream
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        if(StreamService.INT_PLAY_STATE==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        if(StreamService.INT_PLAY_STATE==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
return false;
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are any other buttons affected

Comment: Are you sure you want to stop the user from changing their ringer volume? It's normal behavior on Android devices to change ringer volume when no sound is playing and to change media volume when it is, no matter what app you're in. That's what the user expects to happen from past experience. As you have it, they need to close your app to change their ringer volume. If I was your user, I'd call that an annoyance rather than a feature.

Comment: Hi Louie, yes I agree however its an audio streaming app, most users are telling me its annoying them opening the app, clicking listen (there is a second or two pause whilst the stream connects) and they pre-emptively turn the volume down in case its too loud and instead the ringer volumes goes down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tested, but I think you need to include an else where you call super.onKeyDown, ie:

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
   code
} else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
   more code
} else {
   super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Otherwise, you're capturing all keycodes and returning false after checking the volume codes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) This is the final working code I have:

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        if(StreamService.INT_PLAY_STATE==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        if(StreamService.INT_PLAY_STATE==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: Pants, that didn't come out as I had laid it out :) For anyone else with the same error its here: http://pastebin.com/cJ7Uq0TV

Answer (score 5):

A simpler and more robust way to have the volume keys always control the Media volume is to insert this line into your Activity's `onCreate()`:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. The others had answered my original question however I have in fact swapped my code out for this, its a better method IMO. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Dude, just change the audio context on that activity to media volume:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

EDIT:

```
private AudioManager audio;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Override onKeyDown:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        //your code
        return true;

    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        //your code
        return true;
    } else {

        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    return true;

}
```